# Trying to increase integer value of total coins for root account

Tags: stellar-core

i have changed the earlier values of total coins by adding 1 more zero.

```
const uint64_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_TOTAL_COINS = 10000000000000000000

# if __WORDSIZE == 64
 typedef long long int      int64_t;
```

i have changed the above value from "typedef long int" to "typedf long long int" so that it can store larger value but while installing stellar core it is throwing some error.

My aim is to change the initial coin value by adding 1 more zero.

Comment: It's probably not that trivial since the type definition will also need to be changed for any other kind of amount variables and it's also very likely specified in SCP and XDR definitions. I'd better try to avoid that.

Comment: @sui i tried it. There is lots of dependency. Although its a requirement to change. so i am looking for some solution which can workout